# How to scale up and crop a UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, scale, cgaffinetransform

Here's the code I have but it's crashing ... any ideas?

```
UIImage *tempImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
CGImageRef imgRef = [tempImage CGImage];
 [tempImage release];

 CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
 CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);
 CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
 CGSize size = bounds.size;

 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(4.0, 4.0);

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
 CGContextDrawImage(context, bounds, imgRef);
 UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

What am I missing here?  Basically just trying to scale image up and crop it to be same size as original.

Thanks

Comment: which kind of crash? What is the error message? What line causes crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
CGImageRef imgRef = [tempImage CGImage];
```

Or more precise, the direct follow-up of this line:

```
[tempImage release];
```

You are getting a CF object here, the `CGImageRef`. Core Foundation object only have the retain/release memory management, but no autoreleased objects. Hence, when you release the `UIImage` in the second row, the `CGImageRef` will be deleted as well. And this again means that it's undefined when you try to draw it down there.

I can think of three fixes:

- use autorelease to delay the release of the image: `[tempImage autorelease];`
- move the release to the very bottom of your method
- retain and release the image using `CFRetain` and `CFRelease`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
-(CGImageRef)imageCapture
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
   [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   CGRect rect= CGRectMake(0,0 ,320, 480);

   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], rect);
   return imageRef;
}
```

use the below line whenever you want to capture the screen

```
UIImage *captureImg=[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[self imageCapture]];
```